# Determine the date/time the current app was started from a C# Portable Class Library or Windows Store App?

Tags: c#, .net, process, windows-store-apps, portable-class-library

From a C# Portable Class Library I want to know when the current app was started.  I can't use System.Diagnostics.Process because those functions are not available to Portable Class Libraries, Windows Store Apps, or Windows Phone Apps.  Is there another way to find out when my app was started?  Or am I stuck having to add a singleton class that upon initialization records the date/time and makes it available via a public property?

Comment: Create a local DateTime/static variable in you class (UI for example) and set DateTime.Now to it? Now need to create any classes for that, use what .NET already has.

Comment: As @MPatel mentioned, you just need to create a `public static` property, then have your app initialize it. If you're using Mvvm or any IOC, you can stick it in your `ServiceLocator`.